# Why JTS Topology Suite isValid Check giving false for this Multtipolygon

Tags: jts-topology-suite, ogc-sfs

Here is my MultiPolygon WKT:

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((109.024696 -11.16938, 109.022471 -11.179862, 109.019166 -11.195072, 109.01579 -11.210266, 109.012342 -11.225445, 109.008823 -11.240608, 109.005231 -11.255755, 109.001568 -11.270885, 108.997834 -11.285998, 108.994028 -11.301093, 108.990151 -11.316171, 108.986203 -11.331231, 108.982183 -11.346273, 108.978093 -11.361296, 108.973931 -11.3763, 108.969699 -11.391284, 108.965395 -11.406249, 108.961021 -11.421195, 108.956576 -11.436119, 108.952081 -11.450971, 108.947516 -11.465801, 108.942881 -11.480611, 108.938177 -11.495399, 108.933402 -11.510165, 108.928558 -11.52491, 108.923645 -11.539632, 108.918661 -11.554331, 108.913609 -11.569007, 108.908487 -11.58366, 108.903296 -11.59829, 108.898036 -11.612895, 108.892707 -11.627477, 108.887309 -11.642033, 108.881842 -11.656565, 108.876307 -11.671072, 108.870703 -11.685553, 108.86503 -11.700008, 108.859289 -11.714438, 108.85348 -11.72884, 108.847603 -11.743216, 108.841658 -11.757565, 108.835645 -11.771887, 108.829564 -11.786181, 108.823416 -11.800447, 108.8172 -11.814684, 108.810916 -11.828893, 108.804566 -11.843073, 108.798148 -11.857224, 108.791663 -11.871345, 108.785112 -11.885437, 108.778934 -11.899767, 108.772688 -11.914068, 108.766374 -11.92834, 108.759993 -11.942584, 108.753543 -11.956797, 108.747026 -11.970981, 108.740441 -11.985135, 108.733789 -11.999259, 108.72707 -12.013351, 108.720284 -12.027413, 108.71343 -12.041443, 108.70651 -12.055442, 108.699523 -12.069409, 108.69247 -12.083343, 108.68535 -12.097245, 108.678164 -12.111114, 108.670912 -12.124949, 108.663593 -12.138751, 108.656209 -12.15252, 108.64876 -12.166254, 108.641244 -12.179954, 108.633664 -12.193619, 108.626018 -12.207249, 108.618307 -12.220844, 108.610531 -12.234403, 108.602691 -12.247927, 108.594786 -12.261414, 108.586816 -12.274865, 108.578783 -12.288279, 108.570685 -12.301655, 108.562523 -12.314995, 108.554298 -12.328296, 108.546071 -12.341466, 108.537783 -12.354598, 108.529432 -12.367692, 108.521019 -12.380748, 108.512543 -12.393765, 108.504006 -12.406744, 108.495408 -12.419683, 108.486748 -12.432583, 108.478026 -12.445443, 108.469244 -12.458263, 108.460401 -12.471043, 108.451496 -12.483783, 108.442532 -12.496481, 108.433507 -12.509139, 108.424422 -12.521755, 108.415276 -12.53433, 108.406071 -12.546863, 108.396807 -12.559354, 108.387483 -12.571802, 108.378099 -12.584208, 108.368657 -12.59657, 108.359156 -12.608889, 108.349596 -12.621165, 108.339978 -12.633397, 108.330302 -12.645585, 108.320567 -12.657729, 108.310775 -12.669828, 108.300925 -12.681882, 108.291017 -12.693892, 108.281053 -12.705856, 108.271031 -12.717774, 108.260953 -12.729646, 108.250818 -12.741472, 108.240626 -12.753252, 108.230379 -12.764985, 108.220075 -12.776671, 108.209716 -12.78831, 108.199301 -12.799902, 108.188831 -12.811446, 108.178306 -12.822942, 108.167726 -12.83439, 108.157091 -12.845789, 108.146402 -12.85714, 108.135659 -12.868442, 108.124862 -12.879695, 108.114011 -12.890898, 108.103107 -12.902051, 108.092149 -12.913155, 108.081143 -12.924205, 108.070084 -12.935205, 108.058973 -12.946155, 108.047809 -12.957053, 108.036593 -12.967901, 108.025326 -12.978697, 108.014006 -12.989441, 108.002636 -13.000134, 107.991214 -13.010775, 107.979742 -13.021363, 107.968219 -13.0319, 107.956645 -13.042383, 107.945021 -13.052813, 107.933348 -13.06319, 107.921625 -13.073514, 107.909852 -13.083785, 107.89803 -13.094001, 107.88616 -13.104163, 107.874241 -13.114271, 107.862273 -13.124325, 107.850257 -13.134323, 107.838194 -13.144267, 107.826083 -13.154156, 107.813924 -13.163989, 107.801719 -13.173767, 107.789466 -13.183489, 107.777167 -13.193154, 107.764822 -13.202764, 107.752431 -13.212317, 107.739993 -13.221813, 107.727511 -13.231253, 107.714983 -13.240635, 107.70241 -13.24996, 107.689793 -13.259228, 107.677131 -13.268438, 107.664425 -13.27759, 107.651675 -13.286684, 107.638881 -13.29572, 107.626044 -13.304697, 107.613164 -13.313615, 107.600242 -13.322475, 107.587276 -13.331275, 107.574269 -13.340017, 107.56122 -13.348698, 107.548129 -13.35732, 107.534996 -13.365883, 107.521823 -13.374385, 107.508608 -13.382827, 107.495354 -13.391208, 107.482059 -13.399529, 107.468724 -13.407789, 107.455349 -13.415988, 107.441935 -13.424126, 107.428482 -13.432203, 107.41499 -13.440218, 107.40146 -13.448171, 107.387891 -13.456063, 107.374285 -13.463893, 107.360641 -13.47166, 107.346959 -13.479365, 107.333241 -13.487007, 107.319486 -13.494587, 107.305694 -13.502104, 107.291867 -13.509558, 107.278003 -13.516948, 107.264104 -13.524276, 107.25017 -13.531539, 107.236201 -13.538739, 107.222197 -13.545875, 107.208159 -13.552947, 107.194087 -13.559955, 107.179982 -13.566899, 107.165843 -13.573778, 107.151671 -13.580593, 107.137744 -13.587217, 107.123785 -13.593779, 107.109796 -13.600279, 107.095776 -13.606715, 107.081726 -13.613089, 107.067393 -13.619514, 107.053029 -13.625874, 107.038634 -13.632167, 107.024209 -13.638396, 107.009754 -13.644558, 106.99527 -13.650654, 106.980756 -13.656685, 106.966214 -13.662649, 106.951643 -13.668546, 106.937043 -13.674378, 106.922416 -13.680142, 106.90776 -13.68584, 106.893078 -13.691471, 106.878368 -13.697035, 106.863632 -13.702532, 106.848869 -13.707962, 106.834081 -13.713324, 106.819266 -13.718619, 106.804426 -13.723846, 106.789561 -13.729006, 106.774671 -13.734098, 106.759757 -13.739121, 106.744819 -13.744077, 106.729857 -13.748965, 106.714871 -13.753784, 106.699863 -13.758535, 106.684831 -13.763218, 106.669777 -13.767832, 106.654701 -13.772377, 106.639603 -13.776854, 106.624484 -13.781261, 106.609343 -13.7856, 106.594182 -13.78987, 106.579 -13.79407, 106.563798 -13.798201, 106.548576 -13.802263, 106.533334 -13.806256, 106.518074 -13.810178, 106.502795 -13.814032, 106.487497 -13.817815, 106.472181 -13.821529, 106.456847 -13.825173, 106.441496 -13.828747, 106.426128 -13.832251, 106.410743 -13.835685, 106.395341 -13.839049, 106.379924 -13.842342, 106.36449 -13.845565, 106.349041 -13.848718, 106.333577 -13.851801, 106.318099 -13.854812, 106.302606 -13.857753, 106.29802 -13.858617, 106.282466 -13.861497, 106.266898 -13.864306, 106.251316 -13.867045, 106.235722 -13.869711, 106.220114 -13.872307, 106.204495 -13.874831, 106.188863 -13.877284, 106.173219 -13.879665, 106.157564 -13.881975, 106.141898 -13.884213, 106.126916 -13.886303, 106.111925 -13.888328, 106.096925 -13.890288, 106.081915 -13.892181, 106.066897 -13.89401, 106.051871 -13.895772, 106.036836 -13.897469, 106.021794 -13.8991, 106.006744 -13.900665, 105.991688 -13.902165, 105.976624 -13.903599, 105.961554 -13.904967, 105.946478 -13.906269, 105.931396 -13.907505, 105.916308 -13.908675, 105.901215 -13.909779, 105.885636 -13.910872, 105.870052 -13.911895, 105.854464 -13.912847, 105.83887 -13.913729, 105.823273 -13.914541, 105.807673 -13.915282, 105.792068 -13.915953, 105.776461 -13.916554, 105.760851 -13.917084, 105.745239 -13.917544, 105.729625 -13.917933, 105.714009 -13.918252, 105.698391 -13.9185, 105.682773 -13.918678, 105.667154 -13.918786, 105.651534 -13.918823, 105.635915 -13.91879, 105.620296 -13.918686, 105.604677 -13.918511, 105.58906 -13.918267, 105.573443 -13.917952, 105.557829 -13.917566, 105.542217 -13.91711, 105.526607 -13.916584, 105.510999 -13.915987, 105.495395 -13.91532, 105.479794 -13.914582, 105.464197 -13.913774, 105.448603 -13.912896, 105.433014 -13.911947, 105.41743 -13.910928, 105.401851 -13.909839, 105.386277 -13.908679, 105.37071 -13.90745, 105.355148 -13.90615, 105.339592 -13.90478, 105.324043 -13.903339, 105.308502 -13.901829, 105.292967 -13.900249, 105.277441 -13.898598, 105.261922 -13.896878, 105.246412 -13.895087, 105.230911 -13.893227, 105.215419 -13.891296, 105.200062 -13.889324, 105.184715 -13.887283, 105.169378 -13.885173, 105.154051 -13.882995, 105.138734 -13.880748, 105.123429 -13.878433, 105.108134 -13.876049, 105.092851 -13.873597, 105.07758 -13.871076, 105.062321 -13.868487, 105.047075 -13.86583, 105.031841 -13.863105, 105.01662 -13.860312, 105.001413 -13.85745, 104.986219 -13.854521, 104.97104 -13.851524, 104.955875 -13.848458, 104.940725 -13.845325, 104.92559 -13.842125, 104.91047 -13.838856, 104.895366 -13.83552, 104.880277 -13.832117, 104.865205 -13.828646, 104.85015 -13.825107, 104.835112 -13.821502, 104.820091 -13.817829, 104.805088 -13.814089, 104.790102 -13.810282, 104.775135 -13.806408, 104.760186 -13.802467, 104.745256 -13.798459, 104.730346 -13.794384, 104.715455 -13.790243, 104.700583 -13.786035, 104.685732 -13.781761, 104.670698 -13.777373, 104.655686 -13.772918, 104.640695 -13.768394, 104.625725 -13.763802, 104.610779 -13.759142, 104.595854 -13.754415, 104.580953 -13.74962, 104.566075 -13.744758, 104.55122 -13.739828, 104.536389 -13.734831, 104.521583 -13.729766, 104.506801 -13.724635, 104.492043 -13.719437, 104.477311 -13.714172, 104.462604 -13.70884, 104.447923 -13.703442, 104.433269 -13.697977, 104.41864 -13.692445, 104.404038 -13.686848, 104.389464 -13.681184, 104.374916 -13.675454, 104.360397 -13.669659, 104.345905 -13.663798, 104.331442 -13.657871, 104.317007 -13.651878, 104.302601 -13.645821, 104.288225 -13.639698, 104.273877 -13.633509, 104.25956 -13.627256, 104.245721 -13.621146, 104.23191 -13.614975, 104.218129 -13.608744, 104.204376 -13.602452, 104.190652 -13.5961, 104.176959 -13.589688, 104.163295 -13.583216, 104.149661 -13.576683, 104.136058 -13.570091, 104.122485 -13.56344, 104.108944 -13.556729, 104.095434 -13.549958, 104.081955 -13.543129, 104.068509 -13.53624, 104.055094 -13.529292, 104.040935 -13.522508, 104.02681 -13.51566, 104.012717 -13.508747, 103.998658 -13.50177, 103.984632 -13.494729, 103.970641 -13.487625, 103.956684 -13.480456, 103.942762 -13.473224, 103.928875 -13.465929, 103.915023 -13.45857, 103.901206 -13.451148, 103.887426 -13.443664, 103.873682 -13.436116, 103.859974 -13.428506, 103.846303 -13.420834, 103.832669 -13.413099, 103.819073 -13.405303, 103.805514 -13.397444, 103.791993 -13.389524, 103.77851 -13.381542, 103.765066 -13.373498, 103.751661 -13.365394, 103.738295 -13.357228, 103.724969 -13.349002, 103.711682 -13.340715, 103.698435 -13.332367, 103.685228 -13.323959, 103.672062 -13.315491, 103.658937 -13.306963, 103.64576 -13.298321, 103.632624 -13.289618, 103.619531 -13.280855, 103.606481 -13.272031, 103.593473 -13.263149, 103.580509 -13.254206, 103.567588 -13.245204, 103.55471 -13.236143, 103.541877 -13.227022, 103.529087 -13.217843, 103.516342 -13.208606, 103.503642 -13.19931, 103.490987 -13.189956, 103.478378 -13.180543, 103.465814 -13.171073, 103.453296 -13.161546, 103.440824 -13.151961, 103.428398 -13.142319, 103.41602 -13.13262, 103.403688 -13.122864, 103.391403 -13.113052, 103.379166 -13.103183, 103.366977 -13.093259, 103.354835 -13.083278, 103.342742 -13.073242, 103.330698 -13.063151, 103.318702 -13.053004, 103.306755 -13.042803, 103.294858 -13.032547, 103.283011 -13.022236, 103.271213 -13.011871, 103.259465 -13.001452, 103.247767 -12.990979, 103.236121 -12.980453, 103.224525 -12.969873, 103.21298 -12.95924, 103.201486 -12.948554, 103.190113 -12.937884, 103.17879 -12.927162, 103.167519 -12.916388, 103.1563 -12.905563, 103.145133 -12.894687, 103.134017 -12.88376, 103.122955 -12.872783, 103.111944 -12.861755, 103.100987 -12.850677, 103.090083 -12.83955, 103.079232 -12.828372, 103.068434 -12.817146, 103.05769 -12.80587, 103.047001 -12.794545, 103.036365 -12.783172, 103.025784 -12.77175, 103.015258 -12.76028, 103.004786 -12.748763, 102.99437 -12.737197, 102.984008 -12.725584, 102.973703 -12.713925, 102.963453 -12.702218, 102.953259 -12.690464, 102.943121 -12.678665, 102.93304 -12.666819, 102.923015 -12.654927, 102.913047 -12.64299, 102.903136 -12.631007, 102.893283 -12.618979, 102.883486 -12.606907, 102.873748 -12.59479, 102.864067 -12.582628, 102.854444 -12.570423, 102.84488 -12.558174, 102.835374 -12.545881, 102.825926 -12.533545, 102.816537 -12.521166, 102.807208 -12.508745, 102.797937 -12.496281, 102.788726 -12.483775, 102.779575 -12.471227, 102.770483 -12.458637, 102.761452 -12.446007, 102.75248 -12.433335, 102.743739 -12.420869, 102.735055 -12.408365, 102.72643 -12.395822, 102.717864 -12.383241, 102.709356 -12.370621, 102.700908 -12.357963, 102.692518 -12.345268, 102.684187 -12.332536, 102.675916 -12.319766, 102.667705 -12.306959, 102.659553 -12.294116, 102.651461 -12.281237, 102.643429 -12.268321, 102.635457 -12.25537, 102.627545 -12.242383, 102.619694 -12.229361, 102.611904 -12.216304, 102.604174 -12.203212, 102.596506 -12.190085, 102.588898 -12.176925, 102.581352 -12.163731, 102.573867 -12.150503, 102.566444 -12.137242, 102.559082 -12.123947, 102.551782 -12.11062, 102.544544 -12.097261, 102.537368 -12.083869, 102.530255 -12.070445, 102.523204 -12.05699, 102.516277 -12.043632, 102.509412 -12.030244, 102.502608 -12.016825, 102.495867 -12.003377, 102.489186 -11.989899, 102.482568 -11.976391, 102.476013 -11.962854, 102.469519 -11.949288, 102.463087 -11.935694, 102.456719 -11.922071, 102.450412 -11.90842, 102.444169 -11.894742, 102.437988 -11.881035, 102.43187 -11.867302, 102.425815 -11.853542, 102.419824 -11.839755, 102.413895 -11.825941, 102.40803 -11.812102, 102.402229 -11.798236, 102.396491 -11.784345, 102.390817 -11.770429, 102.385207 -11.756488, 102.37966 -11.742522, 102.374178 -11.728531, 102.368612 -11.714133, 102.363113 -11.69971, 102.357683 -11.685262, 102.352321 -11.670789, 102.347026 -11.656292, 102.3418 -11.641771, 102.336642 -11.627226, 102.331553 -11.612658, 102.326532 -11.598067, 102.321579 -11.583453, 102.316696 -11.568817, 102.311881 -11.554159, 102.307135 -11.539479, 102.302458 -11.524778, 102.29785 -11.510056, 102.293311 -11.495312, 102.288841 -11.480548, 102.284441 -11.465764, 102.28011 -11.450961, 102.275849 -11.436137, 102.271657 -11.421295, 102.267535 -11.406433, 102.263482 -11.391553, 102.259499 -11.376654, 102.255586 -11.361738, 102.251743 -11.346804, 102.24797 -11.331852, 102.244267 -11.316884, 102.240634 -11.301899, 102.237072 -11.286897, 102.233579 -11.27188, 102.230157 -11.256846, 102.226806 -11.241798, 102.223525 -11.226734, 102.220314 -11.211655, 102.217174 -11.196562, 102.214104 -11.181455, 102.211105 -11.166334, 102.208177 -11.151199, 102.20532 -11.136051, 102.202533 -11.120891, 102.199818 -11.105718, 102.197173 -11.090533, 102.194599 -11.075335, 102.192096 -11.060127, 102.189665 -11.044907, 102.187304 -11.029676, 102.185015 -11.014434, 102.182796 -10.999183, 102.180649 -10.983921, 102.178573 -10.96865, 102.176569 -10.953369, 102.174635 -10.938079, 102.172773 -10.922781, 102.170983 -10.907475, 102.169263 -10.89216, 102.167615 -10.876838, 102.166072 -10.86186, 102.164598 -10.846876, 102.163191 -10.831885, 102.161853 -10.816889, 102.160583 -10.801886, 102.159381 -10.786878, 102.158248 -10.771865, 102.157182 -10.756846, 102.156186 -10.741824, 102.155257 -10.726797, 102.154397 -10.711765, 102.153605 -10.696731, 102.152882 -10.681693, 102.152226 -10.666651, 102.15164 -10.651607, 102.151121 -10.636561, 102.150657 -10.621386, 102.150263 -10.606209, 102.149937 -10.591031, 102.149682 -10.575851, 102.149496 -10.56067, 102.149379 -10.545489, 102.149332 -10.530307, 102.149355 -10.515125, 102.149446 -10.499944, 102.149608 -10.484762, 102.149839 -10.469582, 102.150139 -10.454403, 102.150508 -10.439226, 102.150947 -10.42405, 102.151456 -10.408876, 102.152034 -10.393705, 102.152681 -10.378536, 102.153397 -10.363371, 102.154183 -10.348209, 102.155038 -10.33305, 102.155962 -10.317896, 102.156955 -10.302746, 102.158018 -10.2876, 102.159149 -10.272459, 102.16035 -10.257324, 102.16162 -10.242194, 102.162959 -10.22707, 102.164367 -10.211952, 102.165844 -10.19684, 102.167389 -10.181735, 102.169004 -10.166638, 102.170688 -10.151547, 102.172445 -10.136384, 102.174272 -10.121229, 102.176168 -10.106082, 102.178134 -10.090943, 102.180169 -10.075814, 102.182273 -10.060694, 102.184446 -10.045584, 102.186689 -10.030484, 102.189001 -10.015394, 102.191382 -10.000314, 102.193832 -9.985245, 102.196351 -9.970188, 102.198938 -9.955142, 102.201595 -9.940107, 102.20432 -9.925085, 102.207114 -9.910076, 102.209977 -9.895079, 102.212908 -9.880095, 102.215908 -9.865124, 102.218976 -9.850167, 102.222113 -9.835224, 102.225318 -9.820296, 102.228591 -9.805382, 102.231932 -9.790482, 102.235341 -9.775598, 102.238818 -9.76073, 102.242363 -9.745877, 102.245976 -9.731041, 102.249657 -9.71622, 102.253405 -9.701417, 102.257221 -9.68663, 102.261104 -9.671861, 102.265054 -9.65711, 102.268833 -9.642103, 102.27268 -9.627114, 102.276597 -9.612142, 102.280583 -9.597189, 102.284639 -9.582254, 102.288763 -9.567337, 102.292956 -9.55244, 102.297218 -9.537561, 102.301549 -9.522703, 102.305948 -9.507864, 102.310416 -9.493046, 102.314953 -9.478248, 102.319557 -9.463471, 102.32423 -9.448715, 102.328971 -9.43398, 102.33378 -9.419268, 102.338657 -9.404577, 102.343602 -9.389909, 102.348614 -9.375264, 102.353694 -9.360642, 102.358842 -9.346043, 102.364057 -9.331467, 102.369339 -9.316916, 102.374688 -9.302389, 102.380104 -9.287886, 102.385587 -9.273409, 102.391136 -9.258956, 102.396752 -9.244529, 102.401987 -9.231248, 102.407278 -9.217989, 102.412626 -9.204752, 102.418029 -9.191538, 102.423489 -9.178346, 102.429005 -9.165178, 102.434577 -9.152033, 102.440204 -9.138912, 102.445888 -9.125815, 102.451627 -9.112741, 102.457421 -9.099692, 102.46375 -9.085588, 102.470144 -9.071513, 102.476603 -9.057467, 102.483126 -9.043451, 102.489713 -9.029464, 102.496365 -9.015508, 102.503081 -9.001583, 102.509861 -8.987688, 102.516704 -8.973824, 102.523612 -8.959991, 102.530582 -8.94619, 102.537616 -8.932421, 102.544714 -8.918685, 102.551874 -8.904981, 102.559097 -8.891309, 102.566383 -8.877671, 102.568067 -8.874552, 102.569176 -8.872499, 102.61449 -8.86893, 102.659803 -8.865355, 102.705115 -8.861775, 102.750427 -8.85819, 102.795737 -8.854599, 102.841047 -8.851002, 102.886355 -8.8474, 102.931663 -8.843792, 102.97697 -8.840179, 103.022276 -8.836561, 103.067582 -8.832937, 103.112886 -8.829307, 103.158189 -8.825672, 103.203492 -8.822032, 103.248794 -8.818386, 103.294094 -8.814735, 103.339394 -8.811078, 103.380709 -8.807738, 103.426009 -8.804085, 103.471307 -8.800426, 103.516605 -8.796762, 103.561901 -8.793092, 103.607197 -8.789417, 103.652492 -8.785737, 103.697786 -8.782051, 103.743079 -8.778359, 103.788371 -8.774662, 103.833662 -8.77096, 103.878953 -8.767252, 103.924242 -8.763539, 103.969531 -8.759821, 104.014819 -8.756096, 104.060105 -8.752367, 104.105391 -8.748632, 104.150676 -8.744892, 104.153209 -8.744683, 104.198491 -8.740905, 104.243771 -8.737122, 104.272932 -8.734683, 104.31837 -8.734472, 104.363809 -8.734257, 104.409248 -8.734036, 104.454687 -8.733809, 104.500125 -8.733577, 104.545564 -8.73334, 104.591002 -8.733097, 104.63644 -8.732848, 104.681879 -8.732595, 104.727317 -8.732335, 104.772755 -8.732071, 104.818193 -8.731801, 104.863632 -8.731525, 104.90907 -8.731244, 104.954508 -8.730958, 104.999945 -8.730666, 105.045383 -8.730368, 105.090821 -8.730066, 105.136259 -8.729757, 105.181696 -8.729444, 105.226821 -8.729127, 105.27222 -8.727244, 105.300432 -8.726071, 105.344615 -8.736626, 105.388801 -8.747175, 105.393487 -8.748294, 105.437653 -8.758929, 105.481822 -8.76956, 105.525993 -8.780185, 105.570167 -8.790805, 105.578209 -8.792738, 105.622466 -8.803019, 105.666724 -8.813294, 105.699043 -8.820794, 105.700432 -8.821071, 105.744705 -8.831291, 105.788982 -8.841506, 105.83326 -8.851716, 105.877541 -8.86192, 105.921825 -8.872119, 105.966111 -8.882313, 106.010399 -8.892502, 106.05469 -8.902685, 106.098984 -8.912863, 106.143279 -8.923036, 106.180709 -8.931627, 106.224442 -8.943985, 106.268177 -8.956338, 106.311916 -8.968686, 106.347932 -8.978849, 106.386265 -8.989683, 106.430011 -9.002019, 106.473759 -9.01435, 106.517511 -9.026677, 106.558765 -9.038294, 106.601568 -9.053568, 106.644375 -9.068837, 106.687186 -9.084101, 106.73 -9.099361, 106.772817 -9.114615, 106.815639 -9.129864, 106.822932 -9.13246, 106.848765 -9.151072, 106.878487 -9.172183, 106.915428 -9.19857, 106.952374 -9.224954, 106.989325 -9.251334, 107.026283 -9.27771, 107.063245 -9.304082, 107.072654 -9.310794, 107.108309 -9.338891, 107.143969 -9.366985, 107.179635 -9.395075, 107.199598 -9.410794, 107.235254 -9.438903, 107.270915 -9.467008, 107.306582 -9.49511, 107.342255 -9.523207, 107.377933 -9.551302, 107.413618 -9.579392, 107.449308 -9.607479, 107.485004 -9.635562, 107.520706 -9.663641, 107.556414 -9.691717, 107.578209 -9.708849, 107.613818 -9.737055, 107.649432 -9.765258, 107.685052 -9.793456, 107.720678 -9.821651, 107.726265 -9.826072, 107.729876 -9.829683, 107.762324 -9.861432, 107.794779 -9.893177, 107.82724 -9.92492, 107.859707 -9.956659, 107.89218 -9.988395, 107.905154 -10.001072, 107.937834 -10.032603, 107.97052 -10.064131, 107.983765 -10.076905, 108.016557 -10.10833, 108.049355 -10.139751, 108.050154 -10.140516, 108.082735 -10.172162, 108.115322 -10.203804, 108.147916 -10.235443, 108.180516 -10.267079, 108.213123 -10.298711, 108.245736 -10.33034, 108.278356 -10.361966, 108.310982 -10.393588, 108.329598 -10.411627, 108.361658 -10.443818, 108.393724 -10.476005, 108.425797 -10.508189, 108.457876 -10.540369, 108.489962 -10.572546, 108.490154 -10.572738, 108.522208 -10.60495, 108.554268 -10.637159, 108.576988 -10.659977, 108.586335 -10.669364, 108.618409 -10.701566, 108.650489 -10.733765, 108.682577 -10.76596, 108.714671 -10.798152, 108.746772 -10.83034, 108.77888 -10.862525, 108.810995 -10.894707, 108.843116 -10.926885, 108.875245 -10.95906, 108.90738 -10.991231, 108.939523 -11.023399, 108.971672 -11.055563, 109.003829 -11.087724, 109.034972 -11.118861, 109.03497 -11.118875, 109.031953 -11.134143, 109.029441 -11.146548, 109.028864 -11.149397, 109.025704 -11.164637, 109.024696 -11.16938)), ((105.701901 -10.412734, 105.697875 -10.412418, 105.688211 -10.415665, 105.68672 -10.415986, 105.682051 -10.415986, 105.676005 -10.413431, 105.67353 -10.415204, 105.672418 -10.420372, 105.670377 -10.42289, 105.671062 -10.427316, 105.667245 -10.430035, 105.664534 -10.427755, 105.66265 -10.428128, 105.661489 -10.430992, 105.661667 -10.438476, 105.649951 -10.449741, 105.639088 -10.454883, 105.632655 -10.4592, 105.614725 -10.464812, 105.603388 -10.466211, 105.595938 -10.4632, 105.581085 -10.461354, 105.575854 -10.458076, 105.565343 -10.45419, 105.561281 -10.449312, 105.560317 -10.445386, 105.559983 -10.445071, 105.5583 -10.443877, 105.553984 -10.441692, 105.552339 -10.441293, 105.550467 -10.441675, 105.549905 -10.442315, 105.547602 -10.450488, 105.547843 -10.457199, 105.54908 -10.460564, 105.556798 -10.467121, 105.558099 -10.475562, 105.555412 -10.478657, 105.552041 -10.49053, 105.547534 -10.493336, 105.544644 -10.497177, 105.539694 -10.499086, 105.533017 -10.508312, 105.532965 -10.513647, 105.535658 -10.515582, 105.538449 -10.516433, 105.542798 -10.516671, 105.543214 -10.51656, 105.547334 -10.514042, 105.547735 -10.513641, 105.554585 -10.505052, 105.55576 -10.504533, 105.559266 -10.503979, 105.568529 -10.505549, 105.572915 -10.504261, 105.577292 -10.504277, 105.580917 -10.504492, 105.585137 -10.505882, 105.590524 -10.511613, 105.594404 -10.512209, 105.603104 -10.51119, 105.605047 -10.512183, 105.617223 -10.513378, 105.619281 -10.513882, 105.623771 -10.515689, 105.627619 -10.51776, 105.628137 -10.518168, 105.632161 -10.52302, 105.634712 -10.528619, 105.634772 -10.538077, 105.637551 -10.54484, 105.637579 -10.546875, 105.637042 -10.553689, 105.642171 -10.56603, 105.645053 -10.568866, 105.651193 -10.570799, 105.660818 -10.569884, 105.667333 -10.568272, 105.667605 -10.56799, 105.668434 -10.563474, 105.666883 -10.555572, 105.66794 -10.546875, 105.669365 -10.534805, 105.67812 -10.518495, 105.675399 -10.511958, 105.67545 -10.501904, 105.675739 -10.501346, 105.677947 -10.497898, 105.681562 -10.495142, 105.68176 -10.492917, 105.683845 -10.490155, 105.688763 -10.487573, 105.688967 -10.484803, 105.691834 -10.479224, 105.695376 -10.475197, 105.703007 -10.474144, 105.711854 -10.469462, 105.713176 -10.467774, 105.712519 -10.465894, 105.706899 -10.462594, 105.705993 -10.460776, 105.705189 -10.45322, 105.708539 -10.449336, 105.709619 -10.44273, 105.704985 -10.432963, 105.703132 -10.425045, 105.702637 -10.421654, 105.704252 -10.417193, 105.704124 -10.414042, 105.701901 -10.412734)))
```

and when I am performing an isValid check for this geometry I am getting false I have debugged the JTS code and found out that I am getting one nested point which is why I am getting false as the final result.

I want to understand whether this geometry is topologically valid or not according to OGC SFS Specification for SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I check it in QGis I get "nested shells" as the error, which usually means an inner ring is broken. When I split the multipolygon into single parts it is all valid, so I think your actual geometries are ok but the way you have made them into a multipart is wrong some how.

Collecting the two parts together gives a very similar looking WKT (which is too large to view here) but that is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The error is about nested shells. You have one part of a multipolygon overlapping another part of a multipolygon. That is not allowed. If overlap is intentional you must either model that as a geometrycollection or as two distingt, overlapping (multi)polygon geometries. This image shows part of the geometry. Notice the small overlapping polygon part.

[image]

The geometry breaks this Simple Feature rule:

> e) The interior of a MultiPolygon with more than 1 Polygon is not
> connected; the number of connected components of the interior of a
> MultiPolygon is equal to the number of Polygons in the MultiPolygon.